# I am trying to create a cell2mat while-loop but keep getting error: "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch."

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

Here is my code below:

```
clear
clc
T = readtable('aluminumdatalab3.txt','Delimiter',' ');
A = table2array(T(:,1))

i = 1;
while i < 159
    M(i) = cell2mat(A(i));
    i = i+1;
end

X = str2num(M);
```

I have been trying to figure out how to import this data for hours but I just can't get it.  Using `cell2mat(A(1))` works as well as inserting any other number.  It results in a 1X3 matrix.  I don't know how to put it in the loop so that it does it with all 158 rows of data.  Please help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`M(i)` is a scalar element, you can't assign a 1x3 vector to it. Try initialising M as a matrix using `M=nan(158,3)`, then assign rows using `M(i,:) = cell2mat(A(i));`

Relevant documentation:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html

Comment: Hmm, still getting the same error.  I didn't know you could make a matrix that way so I did learn something new.

Comment: @NicholasLovell - What's the error and where is it happening?  The code that Daniel suggested should work if what you said about your data is right.  Also, can you do me a favour and type in `size(A)`, push ENTER in the Command Prompt and tell me what you get?

Comment: I actually tried to start from scratch and then the data wouldn't show up at all, after I already replaced the old data files.  They were in the .txt but I couldn't get anything to happen in matlab like before so I couldn't tell you the error I was getting unfortunately.  I just ended up manually taking the columns I needed in excel and giving them their own .txt file.  They imported fine after that.  I would still like to figure out how this works but like I said, I couldn't get anything to show up to even get that far again.  Thanks for your help guys.